# UICollectionView ui label not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to iOS development and this is my first project that i am doing alone. i am trying to show the feed of my college's unofficial fb page using uicollectionview. I have been trying a lot of different things but nothing seems to work. The uilabel for the name is not being added to the collection view. However before i added the sizeForLabelAtIndexPath method which is to determine the size of the 2 ui labels and the height of the image to be displayed, the name label was working fine

UICollectionViewController.m file

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"DCE Speaks Up";
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1];
// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
NSError *error= nil;

NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/382057938566656/feed?fields=id,full_picture,message,story,created_time,link&access_token=1750413825187852%7CkUl9nlZFPvdGxGZX4WYabKKG2G4"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:feedURL];

NSDictionary *dataDictionary= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
self.feedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *feedTempArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];        //feedTempArray just used for parsing

for (NSDictionary *feedDictionary in feedTempArray) {
    FacebookFeed *fbFeed =[FacebookFeed facebookFeedWithMessage:[feedDictionary objectForKey:@"message"]];
    fbFeed.story = [feedDictionary objectForKey:@"story"];
    fbFeed.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[feedDictionary objectForKey:@"full_picture"]];
    fbFeed.date = [feedDictionary objectForKey:@"created_time"];
    fbFeed.sharedLink = [NSURL URLWithString:[feedDictionary objectForKey:@"link"]];
    [self.feedArray addObject:fbFeed];
}



// Register cell classes
[self.collectionView registerClass:[FacebookCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
FacebookCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.feed = self.feedArray[indexPath.row];
cell.sizeDictionary = [self sizeForLabelAtIndexPath:indexPath.row collectionView:collectionView];
// Configure the cell
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }else if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;          
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
return cell;
}
#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *sizeDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    sizeDictionary = [self sizeForLabelAtIndexPath:indexPath.row collectionView:collectionView];
        return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 20, [sizeDictionary[@"imageHeight"] floatValue] + [sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue] + [sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue]);
}
#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>
- (NSDictionary *) sizeForLabelAtIndexPath:(NSUInteger)indexPath collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
FacebookFeed *feed = self.feedArray[indexPath];
CGSize nameSize = CGSizeFromString(@"DCE Speaks Up");
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
if (feed.imageURL) {
    imageSize = CGSizeMake(470, 394);
}
float height = 80;
NSString *string = @"";
if (feed.message) {
    string = [feed.message stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}else if (feed.story){
    string = [feed.story stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
if (string) {
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]
                                 };
    CGRect bodyFrame =
    [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds),
                                            CGFLOAT_MAX)
                         options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin)
                      attributes:attributes
                         context:nil];

    height += ceilf(CGRectGetHeight(bodyFrame));
}
return @{ @"imageHeight" : @(imageSize.height) , @"messageHeight" : @(height) , @"nameHeight" : @(nameSize.height)};
}
```

Custom cell file

```
@implementation FacebookCollectionViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // change to our custom selected background view
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

-(void) setFeed:(FacebookFeed *)feed{
_feed = feed;
self.messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.messageLabel.lineBreakMode = 0;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:feed.imageURL];
    UIImage *theImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.imageView.image= theImage ;
    });
});
if (feed.message) {
    self.messageLabel.text =  [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[feed.message stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}else{
    self.messageLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[feed.story stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}
self.messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:11];
[self.messageLabel sizeToFit];
self.nameLabel.text = @"DCE Speaks Up";
[self.nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12]];
[self.nameLabel sizeToFit];
}
-(void) layoutSubviews{
NSLog(@"%@",self.feed);
self.nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, [self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue]);
float height = 200;
if (self.contentView.bounds.size.height - [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue] -[self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue] >100) {
    height = self.contentView.bounds.size.height - [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue] -[self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue];
}
if (self.feed.imageURL) {
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue] +[self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue], self.contentView.bounds.size.width - 20,height);
    self.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue] +10, self.contentView.bounds.size.width - 10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue]);

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.messageLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];

}else{
    self.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue], self.contentView.bounds.size.width - 10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue]);
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.messageLabel];
}
[self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];

} 
@end
```

[image: The name label does not appear although it was present before i used sizeForLabel method which i created to get dynamic cell height]

[image: THE JSON URL]

Comment: You're better off sticking to a specific problem you're having instead of posting all these screenshots.  People here are very helpful but you don't have a question associated with all this code and screenshots.

Comment: These all are specific problems because the code i posted should be giving a proper output but the output is unexpected thats why i dont know what is causing what